# How to Consume Web service in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am new to Android development
i have a web service made in php now i want to consume it in android can any one guide me how to achieve this..???

i have tried many code samples on net but failed to achieve this goal.
i am using Eclipse with ADT.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I think we need more information about how much data you are sending, and in what format.

Can you add to the PHP web service or is it owned by someone else?

Comment: could you please provie me sample code in achieving this i am new to java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly go through the following link. you will find code examples here
http://www.anddev.org/calling_a_web_service_from_android-t348.html

Comment: It's boring. Read this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/ because explains how to properly and in short steps achieve web service consumption.

Answer (score -1):

Android is developed using Java platform. what you should do is  create a WebService and expose the WSDL via HTTP.

write your java program calling this Webservice.

its easier and simpler.

Comment: could you please give me example of that?? or a sample code.??