# how to get app to consume web service

Tags: android, asp.net, .net, sqlite

I have created my first android app on my phone that contains a SQLite database. I will be the only person whoever uses this app.

I also have a SQL server database on my home PC. The SQLite database contains 4 tables that are in my SQL server database.

So I want to be able to sync my SQLite database to my SQL server database from time to time.

I have been googling how to do this and read that I need to create a web service. I have read some tutorials on this and it seems that I will be able to do this without too much hassle in .net.

My question is how do I get my android app to consume my web service? Or am I barking up the wrong tree completely?

Comment: for this you need web services. create api and also create app where you can change Host_Url dynamically so that you can connect with your PC. PC and your mobile should be in same network to work successfully

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Consume Web service in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058376/how-to-consume-web-service-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do is create a RESTful API.
A rest api basically functions as a controller between your database and the client which would be your app. Your app will basically 'talk' (request) to your rest api because it wants to retrieve data from the database. The rest api then talks to the database to get the data the app wants and sends this data in a http response to the client (your app). More info on restful api's [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

In order to let your app communicate with a rest api, you need a http client. The most popular and easy to use http client is retrofit, which you can find  [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

There's alot of documentation and tutorials for retrofit out there, so the rest is up to your google-fu skills.

Good luck!